# GMock: Why does EXPECT_CALL leak std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, googletest, unique-ptr, googlemock

In the following straight-forward test, GTest complains that mock is never deleted. I don't understand this behavior. If I remove the `EXPECT_CALL`, it works fine.

```
TEST_F(TestFixture, TestName)
{
    auto mock_client = std::make_unique<MockClient>();
    auto mock_evaluator = std::make_unique<MockEvaluator>();

    // problematic expect call
    EXPECT_CALL(*mock_client, DoSomething(testing::_)).Times(1);

    Runner runner(std::move(mock_client), std::move(mock_evaluator));
}
```

I get the following error:

```
xyz_test.cpp:48: ERROR: this mock object (used in test TestFixture.TestName) should be deleted but never is. Its address is @0x865510.
ERROR: 1 leaked mock object found at program exit. Expectations on a mock object is verified when the object is destructed. Leaking a mock means that its expectations aren't verified, which is usually a test bug. If you really intend to leak a mock, you can suppress this error using testing::Mock::AllowLeak(mock_object), or you may use a fake or stub instead of a mock.
```

Can someone please help me understand this behavior?

Comment: Can you add some more details, like the full error message about the leak? In your current code snippet there is no directly leaked object. Maybe in the `SetUp` code of the test fixture?

Comment: @CoryKramer I have updated the question to include the error message

Comment: Missing `virtual` destructor of base class perhaps?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen missing virtual destructor of the base class was the issue. Can you please write an answer so that I mark it as correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

By using a `unique_ptr`, the owner of the mock object becomes the `runner` object. GTest's leak detection expects `mock_client` and `mock_evaluator` to be destructed within your TEST, not possibly after that.

GMock will verify the expectations on a mock object when it is destructed. See this [reference](https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cheat_sheet.html#verifying-and-resetting-a-mock).

You can either avoid using a unique pointer and construct the mock object in your test and just pass its address to your `runner` object, or add this at the end of your test:

```cpp
EXPECT_TRUE(Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations(mock_client.get()));
EXPECT_TRUE(Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations(mock_evaluator.get()));
```

This verifies and removes the expectations on your mock objects and returns true if and only if successful.

Comment: `runner` is destroyed by the end of `TEST_F` body, so unless it calls `release()` in its constructor on the `unique_ptr`s, the `unique_ptr`s will be destroyed correctly before the end of the test. Or unless it moves the pointers further to something that outlives `Runner`.

Comment: That is right. We don't know what runner does with the pointer.  It might move it to something else that outlives the test.